# Different ways to add text using Javascript

Tags: javascript

So far I know of two methods which I don't really prefer using:

```
var newText = document.createTextNode("New Text");
someDiv.appendChild( newText );
```

or this method:

```
someDiv.innerText = "New Text";
someDiv.innerHtml = <em>"New Text"</em>; //or something like this I forget the exact syntax.
```

Is there no way to position text like images using css style? My preferred method would be something like this:

```
var newText = document.createTextNode("New Text");
someDiv.appendChild( newText );
newText.style.position = "absolute";
newText.style.top = "150px";
newText.style.left = "300px";
```

Anyone know if this would be possible without creating a new div for every single text that I want positioned somewhere specific? I couldn't find anything of the sort.

As a side note question, would creating 50 divs just for text be considered bad coding?

Thanks in advance for any information, sorry for the lame question

Edit:

Thanks for everyone's help, seems to work out perfectly like this:

```
    var testSpan = document.createElement("span")
    testSpan.innerText = "Testing";
    someDiv.appendChild(testSpan);
    testSpan.style.position = "absolute";
    testSpan.style.left = "500px";
```

Comment: You don't need a div, but you do need some sort of element, even if that is a span.

Comment: by nature of xml, the markup is there to determine what happens with the content... content can't determine that itself.

Comment: PS. `textContent` is the more 'proper' way to spell setting text; `innerText` is the workaround for IE<9 where that's not supported.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brad for the span solution. And also thanks bobince for telling me the correct way to add text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add a `className to the div` instead of setting the style for each div.

```
newText.className = "newDiv";

.className {
     position : absolute;
     top      : 150px;
     left     : 300px;
}
```

To target any particular element it should be defined inside an element for which you apply styling. So you ought to create some element that acts a container to hold the corresponding txt.

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. The className would definitely work just fine. I'll probably use the span idea though so I don't have to switch files to code from css to js.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't create div or span, the standard orders the browser to create [anonymous inline box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous) around any free text element anyway - so don't worry and `document.createElement("span")` with className as Susanth suggests - it is not bad coding: if you want to position them, they deserve explicit box element.

Comment: Thanks so much for specifying that the standard orders the browser to create an inline box anyway. After Brad's comment I went ahead and created some code, which worked perfectly. Only thing I was worried about was if it'd be 'bad coding', but you just gave me my answer. Thanks a lot for that, put my mind at ease.